# Javascript and forms

Tags: javascript

This is my html:

```
<form id="questions">
<p>Answer: <input type="text" name="textbox1" size="30" /> 
<button onclick="answers()">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
function answers () {
   var x = document.getElementById("questions");
   var y = x.elements["textbox1"].value;
   document.write("Hello " +y);
}
```

My issue is when I click the button, it flashes the document.write string for a split second. I'm not sure why it's only happening for a split second.

Comment: You shouldn't have a `<form>` at all.

Comment: @SLaks—the OP seems to be just starting out and testing getting the value of a form control and writing it to the page. As an example, using a form as in the OP is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though there is no action on your form, some browsers still reload the page on submission, and my guess is this is what's happening.

If you return false on the onclick event, it will stop the default behaviour. You should add an action to the form too, to comply with standards.

```
<form id="questions" action="#">
    <p>Answer: <input type="text" name="textbox1" size="30" /> 
    <button onclick="return answers()">Submit</button></p>
</form>

function answers () {
   var x = document.getElementById("questions");
   var y = x.elements["textbox1"].value;
   document.write("Hello " +y);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: That won't help; you aren't returning from the handler.

Comment: As I test it out, "action" didn't make a difference but adding "return" both on the html and on javascript made the difference. How does this conceptually work?

Answer (score 1):

try putting

```
type="button"
```

in your button element

Comment: @SLaks it may do, actually. The default type is submit, so by changing it to button, it won't submit the form.

Comment: @SLaks—a [*button type button*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#attr-button-type) does nothing. @Jacob—the OP also needs to not use [*document.write*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/webappapis.html#dom-document-write) as if called after the page has finished loading, it will first clear the document before writing.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `document.write()`; it will replace the page.
  Instead, use the DOM APIs.
- You need to `return false` from the handler to prevent the default action of submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

return false to avoid the form to be submited

```
  function answers () {
  var x = document.getElementById("questions");
   var y = x.elements["textbox1"].value;
  document.write("Hello " +y);
  return false;
 }
```